# Just cannot understand pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having a really frustrating time trying to understand pointers, literally 90% of the errors I get when coding revolve entirely around pointers

So I have a char* array, mallocced and holding characters

strcpy only takes pointers for some reason, so if I want to strcpy array[x] to a destination, I can't just use

```
strcpy(destination,array[x])
```

because that gives me an error saying array[x] is a char, not a char*

now here's the thing I don't get - how do I make a pointer to array[x]? I don't understand pointers at all

When I use

```
char i;
char *j;
i = array[0];
j = &i;
strcpy(destination,j);
```

It gives me the letter, but with accompanying junk chars despite the fact I memsetted j before assigning it to &i

When I use

```
char *j;
j = &array[0];
strcpy(destination,j);
```

It adds the entire array

What's the difference? I'm assigning J to the address of x[0] in both cases aren't I?

Comment: Do you want to copy a single character? If so, `strcpy` is the wrong tool, just assign it.

Comment: "So I have a char* array, mallocced and holding characters" -- You unfortunately didn't show us the piece of code declaring `array`,  making your statement (and question) somewhat ambiguous. Do you have a `char * array = malloc( ... )`, i.e. a pointer to an array of characters, or do you have an array of `char *`, i.e. an array of character *pointers*? That would be two rather different things.

Comment: It was declared as

`char *array = malloc(...)` as you said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have lost track of where the variables are and what you are copying.  Here is your code annotated with what it is doing.

```
char i;          // reserves a variable of size char on the stack
char *j;         // reserves a variable of size ptr on the stack
i = array[0];    // copies the first char from the array 
                 // into variable i
j = &i;          // copies the stack address of variable i into j.. 
                 // note that this is not the array as we 
                 // previously copied the char out of the array  
strcpy(destination,j);  // you have not supplied destination, so 
                        // no comment there but j is a pointer 
                        // onto the stack AND NOT a pointer 
                        // into the array.. thus who knows
                        // what characters it will copy afterwards
```

where as version 2 is different:

```
char *j;               // reserves a variable on the stack of size ptr
j = &array[0];         // sets the contents of variable j to the address 
                       // of the first element of the array.. note
                       // that this is the same as `j = array`
strcpy(destination,j); // starts copying the chars from j into 
                       // destination, incrementing the pointer j 
                       // one at a time until a null is found and 
                       // the copying will stop
```

So in conclusion, version 2 is copying the array.. where as version 1 is copying data from the stack after copying the first character of the array onto the stack.  Thus the behaviour is different.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy (dest, src)` will try to copy the src string to destination, till if finds null terminator (\0).

```
char i;
char *j;
i = array[0];
j = &i;
strcpy(destination,j);
```

`i` is a new variable allocated on the stack (Remember `i` and `array` have different memory locations) and you have assigned a pointer `j` which points to it. That's why you are seeing some garbage characters, since strcpy will copy starting from the memory location of `i` till it finds '\0'.

```
char *j;
j = &array[0];
strcpy(destination,j);
```

In this case, `j` is pointing to the array (first character), `strcpy` will copy the entire `array` to the destination by the same logic explained above.

The difference is that `j` in the first case is not the pointer to the same memory location where `array` is allocated. You have explicitly defined a new variable `i` and variable `j` points to the memory location of variable `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The string copy function expects this:

```
strcpy(destination,array)
```

So it will copy the bytes from `array[0]` until the terminating `\0` character into the `destination` array.

If you need a single character copied, then do not use `strcpy` for this. By the way `&array[0]` is exactly the same as `array`. They both contain the address of the first item of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding pointers is to realize they are nothing magical but merely a plain integer variable meant to hold a memory address. Every variable in your program has a memory address, because that's how computers work. These addresses are very convenient to have access to, for many reasons.

`strcpy` don't expect "pointers", but rather it expects *strings*. A string in C is an array of characters ending with a null termination character `\0`.

There's a rule in C saying that whenever you use an array name in an expression, such as `destination`, it gets translated to a pointer to the first element in that array. This is why `strcpy()` wants pointers.

Actually, you can't even pass arrays to functions in C, because the would make programs very slow, having to copy the array each time. Just passing the address to the first item in the array goes much quicker.

`strcpy(destination,array[x])` doesn't work because `array[x]` is a character, not a string.

Now when you copy that character into the variable `i`, you still have a single character, but it is not a string, because strings are null terminated. When you take the address of `i` through a pointer and give it to `strcpy`, you "lie" to `strcpy` and tell the function "here is a string". But it is not a string, because there is no null termination.

`strcpy` then expects to find a null termination somewhere after the character. Therefore it prints the character, and continues printing random stuff in the memory which happened to be allocated just after the variable `i`. It will continue to do this until it finds a memory cell with the value zero. Usually this would cause a program crash.

You could fix this by doing like this:

```
char i[2];
i[0] = array[x];
i[1] = '\0'; // null termination
strcpy(destination, i);
```

In `strcpy(destination, i);` the array `i` decays into a pointer to the first element, so you don't even need the separate pointer variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you write this:

```
j = &array[0];
```

It means that you are going to take the entire string from the first character until the end.

But when you just write:

```
i = array[0];
j = &i;
```

It means that you are just assigning the value of the first character of your array.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's take some time to talk about strings, arrays, pointers, and how they all relate to each other.

We'll start with a short example program and its output to illustrate some concepts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dumper.h"

int main( void )
{
  char arr[] = "Hello";
  char *buf = malloc( strlen( arr ) + 1 );
  if ( buf )
    strcpy( buf, arr );
  char *ptr = "Hello";

  printf( "    address of \"Hello\" string literal: %p\n", (void *) "Hello" );
  putchar( '\n' );

  printf( "              address of arr variable: %p\n", (void *) &arr );
  printf( "                value of arr variable: %p\n", (void *) arr );
  printf( "             contents of arr variable: %s\n", arr );
  putchar( '\n' );

  printf( "              address of buf variable: %p\n", (void *) &buf );
  printf( "                value of buf variable: %p\n", (void *) buf );
  printf( "    string pointed to by buf variable: %s\n", buf );
  putchar( '\n' );

  printf( "              address of ptr variable: %p\n", (void *) &ptr );
  printf( "                value of ptr variable: %p\n", (void *) ptr );
  printf( "    string pointed to by ptr variable: %s\n", ptr );
  putchar( '\n' );

  char *names[] = {"\"Hello\"", "arr", "buf", "*buf", "ptr"};
  void *addrs[] = {"Hello", arr, &buf, buf, &ptr};
  size_t lens[] = {sizeof "Hello", sizeof arr, sizeof buf, strlen( buf ), sizeof ptr };

  dumper( names, addrs, lens, 5, stdout );

  free( buf );

  return 0;
}
```

and here's the output:

```
address of "Hello" string literal: 0x400de8

          address of arr variable: 0x7fff7018cc30
            value of arr variable: 0x7fff7018cc30
         contents of arr variable: Hello

          address of buf variable: 0x7fff7018cc28
            value of buf variable: 0x502010
string pointed to by buf variable: Hello

          address of ptr variable: 0x7fff7018cc20
            value of ptr variable: 0x400de8
string pointed to by ptr variable: Hello

       Item        Address   00   01   02   03
       ----        -------   --   --   --   --
    "Hello"       0x400de8   48   65   6c   6c    Hell
                  0x400dec   6f   00   00   00    o...

        arr 0x7fff7018cc30   48   65   6c   6c    Hell
            0x7fff7018cc34   6f   00   00   00    o...

        buf 0x7fff7018cc28   10   20   50   00    ..P.
            0x7fff7018cc2c   00   00   00   00    ....

       *buf       0x502010   48   65   6c   6c    Hell
                  0x502014   6f   00   00   00    o...

        ptr 0x7fff7018cc20   e8   0d   40   00    ..@.
            0x7fff7018cc24   00   00   00   00    ....
```

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values followed by a 0-valued *terminator*.  Strings are *stored* as `N`+1 arrays of `char`, where `N` is the length of the string not counting the terminator<sup>1</sup>.  Three examples of strings above are the string literal `"Hello"`, the array `arr`, and the expression `*buf`.  The dump output above for each of those expressions shows the sequence of ASCII values corresponding to `"Hello"`, followed by a 0-valued byte (there are a couple more 0-valued bytes following the terminator, but they are not part of the array).

Most string processing functions in C (such as `strcpy`) expect a pointer to the first element of the string (`char *`); they'll then "walk" down the string until they see the terminator.

Arrays in C are simply contiguous sequences of elements of a given type; arrays do not store any metadata about their size or properties of their elements, nor do they store a pointer value to the first element of the array (again, this is evident from the dump output above).  Arrays may not be the target of the `=` assignment operator, nor may functions return array types.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array (such as in the code above), an *expression* of type "`N`-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and its value will be the address of the first element of the array<sup>3</sup>.  So in the line

```
strcpy( buf, arr );
```

the array expression `arr` is not an operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and it isn't a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, so the compiler implicitly converts it from type "6-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`" (`char *`), and its value is the address of the first element of the array.  Same for `strlen`.

Array indexing is done in terms of pointer operations.  The expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)`.  We take an address `a`, offset `i` elements (*not bytes!*) from it to get a new address, and then dereference the result.  This is why `buffer[i]` has type `char`, not `char *`.  This also means that `a + i` will give different results based on the type of `a`.  Assume the following:

```
int *a    = 0x1000;
char *b   = 0x1000;
double *c = 0x1000;
```

The expression `a + 1` will evaluate to `0x1000 + sizeof (int)`; assuming a 4-byte `int`, you'll get `0x1004`.  The expression `b + 1` will evaluate to `0x1001` (`sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition).  The expression `c + 1` will evaluate to `0x1001 + sizeof (double)`; assuming an 8-byte double, this will result in `0x1008`.

Note that in the output above, the expressions `&arr` and `arr` returned the same *value* - the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array - but they have different *types*.  `&arr` has type "pointer to 6-element array of `char`", or `char (*)[6]`, whereas `arr` has type "pointer to `char`".

The variables `buf` and `ptr` are simple pointers to `char`; they store the *addresses* of other `char` objects in memory (see the dump output - the contents of `ptr` make up the address of `"Hello"`, stored in little-endian order).  `buf` gets assigned the output of the `malloc` call, which is the address of the first element of a dynamically allocated buffer on the heap.  `ptr` gets assigned the address of the first element of the `"Hello"` string literal.

Given all of that, here's a table of various expressions, their types, and their corresponding values:

```
 Expression        Type            "Decays" to        Value
 ----------        ----            -----------        -----
    "Hello"        char [6]        char *             Address of first element in string literal
   &"Hello"        char (*)[6]     n/a                Address of string literal object (yes, you can do this)
   *"Hello"        char            n/a                Value of first element of string literal object ('H') (yes, you can do this)
 "Hello"[i]        char            n/a                Value of i'th element of string literal (yes, you can do this)
&"Hello"[i]        char            n/a                Address of i'th element of string literal

        arr        char [6]        char *             Address of first element in array
       &arr        char (*)[6]     n/a                Address of array object
       *arr        char            n/a                Value of first element in array ('H')
     arr[i]        char            n/a                value of i'th element in array
    &arr[i]        char *          n/a                Address of i'th element in array

        buf        char *          n/a                Address of first element in dynamically allocated buffer
       &buf        char **         n/a                Address of buf variable
       *buf        char            n/a                Value of first element in dynamically allocated buffer
     buf[i]        char            n/a                Value of i'th element in dynamically allocated buffer
    &buf[i]        char *          n/a                Address of i'th element in dynamically allocated buffer

        ptr        char *          n/a                Address of first element in string literal
       &ptr        char **         n/a                Address of ptr variable
       *ptr        char            n/a                Value of first element in string literal
     ptr[i]        char            n/a                Value of i'th element in string literal
    &ptr[i]        char *          n/a                Address of i'th element in string literal
```

Note that the types and values of `&"Hello"` and `&arr` differ from the types and values of `&buf` and `&ptr`.  Again, `&arr` and `arr` refer to the same memory location (the address of the array is the address of the first element of the array), but the types are different.  `&buf` and `buf` do not - `&buf` is the address of the pointer variable `buf`, which contains the address of another object in memory.  Note also that `&buf` and `&ptr` have type `char **` - "pointer to pointer to `char`", which is a different type from `char (*)[6]`.

As I mentioned above, almost all string processing routines expect their arguments to have type `char *`<sup>4</sup>, and they expect that pointer to correspond to the address of the first element of a string - that is, a sequence of characters terminated by a 0-valued byte.  The table above will show you which expressions have the correct type for such an operation.  If you wanted to copy the last 3 characters of `"Hello"` to `buf`, you could write

```
strcpy( buf, &arr[2] );
```

`&arr[2]` has type `char *`, and is the address of the first `'l'` character in `"Hello"`, so this would copy the substring `"llo"` to `buf`.

One more thing:

```
printf( "                value of arr variable: %p\n", (void *) arr );
printf( "             contents of arr variable: %s\n", arr );
```

We're passing the same pointer *value* to `printf`, but we get different output because the conversion specifiers `%p` and `%s` treat that pointer value differently.  `%p` expects its corresponding argument to have type `void *` and displays the pointer value in a platform-dependent manner<sup>5</sup>.  `%s` expects its corresponding argument to have type `char *` and expects it to point to a string, and it will output the sequence of characters in that string until it sees the string terminator.

---

1. C also allows for wide and multibyte (such as UTF-8) strings to represent extended and non-English character sets, which will stored as arrays of `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `char` (for UTF-8), and the terminator will be appropriate for the type and encoding.

   The wide disparity in the address values has to do with where and how string literals are stored vs. variables allocated on the stack.  This varies by implementation, and we're not going to discuss it in detail here.

   There are a couple of other exceptions, but we don't need to worry about them here.

   Actually, the prototypes of most string processing routines use `const char * restrict` for their argument types, which means the routine assumes it cannot modify the input through the pointer (it points to `const char`) and that multiple inputs do not overlap in memory (`restrict`).

   This is probably the only place in C where you should explicitly cast a pointer value to `void *`.  The output can vary from system to system because the internal representation of a pointer value can vary from system to system.  Some treat it as an unsigned integer, some treat it as a pair of values representing a page number and an offset into the page, some can use an entirely different representation.  Pointers to different types may have different sizes and representations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly where the reasoning error is occurring for you but:

Pointers are like indexes into the "array" that is the whole machine memory.

Different variables are in different places within machine memory.

So "&i" is always going to be a different value than "&array[0]".

Your "i = array[0]" is a char assignment (both sides are of type "char") -- the single char at &array[0] is copied to location &i.

The characters following &i in machine memory are indeterminate -- they are outside the defined bounds of any variable, thus the "junk".